# What do two exclamation marks `!!` follow the version mean in gradle dependencies

Tags: gradle, version

The `build.gradle` file of a project I'm working on contains the following line

```
implementation platform("com.example:fizz-buzz:0.0.1!!")
```

What do two exclamation marks, `!!`, following the version mean?

The search in https://docs.gradle.org/ does not return any useful results, nor does Google when searching for `site:docs.gradle.com "!!"`

Comment: Never seen that before...  I assume the above is an example made up for this question...  Do you have the actual line?

Comment: Does Gradle accept it? Or do you see an error?

Comment: Actual line is  `implementation platform("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:${springBootVersion}!!")`

Answer (score 1):

Got the answer from a colleague :)

> There is, however, a shorthand notation for strict versions, using the !! notation:

```
dependencies {
    // short-hand notation with !!
    implementation('com.example:fizz-buzz:0.0.1!!')
    // is equivalent to
    implementation('com.example:fizz-buzz') {
        version {
           strictly '0.0.1'
        }
    }
}
```

[Simple version declaration semantics](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/single_versions.html#simple_version_declaration_semantics)

> **strictly**
>
> Any version not matched by this version notation will be excluded. This is the strongest version declaration. On a declared dependency, a strictly can downgrade a version. When on a transitive dependency, it will cause dependency resolution to fail if no version acceptable by this clause can be selected. See overriding dependency version for details. This term supports dynamic versions.
>
> When defined, overrides previous require declaration and clears previous reject.

[Declaring Rich Versions](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/rich_versions.html#header)